# OpenSSL "Self-signed certificate encountered" error v1.0.1c

Tags: openssl, wget

Why does  `wget https://www.asb.co.nz` give `Self-signed certificate encountered` error in a system running openssl 1.0.1c and goes fine in a system running 0.9.8g?

Comment: newer version = better security checks? Why don't you test it against openssl 0.9.8y and see if the error is there?

Comment: I have different version in different servers. One is the latest version and I am getting these errors. Does it have anything to do with certificate paths?